# sorting of strings with ascii and length of the strings

Tags: string, sorting

we have to input n strings and sort it in ascending order where sorting takes place by the length as well as ascii values.
please help....
there is a sample test case :
no of strings 5
omar
apple
banana
ant
cat

the output must be :
ant cat omar apple banana

```
enter code here:
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    int n,i,l,m,j;
    char str[20][20],temp[20],temp2[20][20];
    printf("enter no of strings\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
// string is given as input
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s",str[i]);
        l=strlen(str[i]);
        printf("len is %d\n",l);
    }
//sorting on the basis of length
    for(i=0; i<=n; i++)
        for(j=i+1; j<=n; j++)
        {
            if(strlen(str[i])>strlen(str[j]))
            {
                strcpy(temp,str[i]);
                strcpy(str[i],str[j]);
                strcpy(str[j],temp);
            }
        }
//sorting on the basis of ascii values
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(l==m)// spcl condition
        {
            printf("\ncheck",l,m);
            for(j=0; j<strlen(str[i]); j++)
            {
                if(strcmp(str[j][i],str[j][++i])>0)
                {
                    strcpy(temp2[20],str[i]);
                    strcpy(str[i],str[++i]);
                    strcpy(str[++i],temp2[20]);
                }
            }
        }
        else// default condition
        {
            strcpy(temp2[20],str[i]);
            strcpy(str[i],str[++i]);
            strcpy(str[++i],temp2[20]);
        }
    }
//display each string
    printf("the strings are\n");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%s",str[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy enough.

qsort takes a user-defined comparison function. So compare lengths first. If they are equal, call strcmp to compare alphabetically.

If you need to implement qsort, write a bubblesort with the same interface first to get things working, then replace with a faster algorithm.